# kvm console not working at login [centos on centos]

Tags: centos, kvm, virtualization

When I run the following

```
$su
$virsh console myvm
```

I keep getting

> login incorrect

, even though I'm typing the correct password. In fact, it does work if I use virt-viewer.

What could it be?

Comment: Is `ttyS0` contained in `/etc/securetty`?

Comment: do I just add it to the guest machine (and restart?)?

Comment: Rebooting should not be necessary.